# How can I improve or reduce redundancy of this javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

I'm trying to concatenate a string from certain inputs in a form, and populate another input with that string. I've included my script below, and linked to a js fiddle.

I think the code inside the conditionals in the each() is too redundant, but I can't seem to make it work any other way. Any suggestions are appreciated.

```
var $namers = $(".namer");
$namers.on('change', function () {
    var length = $namers.length - 1;
    var nameString = "";
    $namers.each(function (i) {
        var delimiter = "";
        if ($(this).find(":selected").attr('value')) {
            if (i < length) delimiter = ": ";
            thisVal = $(this).find(":selected").text();
            nameString = nameString + thisVal + delimiter;
        } else if ($(this).is("input") && $(this).val()) {
            if (i < length && $(this).hasClass("from")) delimiter = "-";
            thisVal = $(this).val();
            nameString = nameString + thisVal + delimiter;
        }
    });
    $("#summary").val(nameString);
});
```

Here is my original:
http://jsfiddle.net/3HsQW/

And a first stab at improving things using an array, which I'm not sure is much better.
http://jsfiddle.net/3HsQW/1/

Comment: I do not see any redundancy, except for the nameString line. I do however find useless code: the `nameString` variable belongs to the anonymous function created on line 2. Each run of the anonymous functions used on the `.each()` call is tested, and in case it passes any of the conditions, `nameString` gets set. Only the last one of this assignments will be loaded into `$('#sumary')`. If this is the intended behaivour, you should transverse the `$namers` the other way around and break after finding the first hit.

Comment: Questions like this belong on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/, not here.

Comment: @jfriend00 Thanks. I didn't know about that site. I'll see if I can close the question.

Comment: @MartínValdésdeLeón That is correct, I think. I'm not clear what part of the code you are saying is useless. Also, what is the advantage of transversing $namers in reverse? Is it to remove the i<length conditional?

Comment: A more relevant issue may be how little the code says about what its intent is:ambiguous logic/weak model. If you're worried about performance you should assign `$(this)` to not continually call jQuery.  Any reason not to use the labels to also be the values in the select? The biggest performance gain would be to remove the loop entirely (& repeated DOM inspection) & only react to the single control that has changed-using something like a stripped down bound model:create an in-memory structure and only update the piece that is relevant which can then be manipulated to produce the summary.

Comment: Sorry, *useless* is not the correct term. What I meant to say by *useless* is that you have code which is ran and ends up doing nothing except wasting CPU. The whole point of the anonymous function inside the `each()` call is to calculate `nameString`. Besides that, it does nothing. Yet, after going through your `$namers` and generating `nameString` possibly many times, only the last value generated remains available. Thus, calculating the previous values for `nameString` was a waste of CPU.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried both of the other answers, and neither worked. I also learned I should be using http://codereview.stackexchange.com.

I ultimately decided on this (though I have reservations about whether this will help anyone else):

```
var $namers = $(".namer");
$namers.on('change', function () {
    var length = $namers.length - 1;
    var nameString = "";
    var names = [];
    $namers.each(function (i) {
        var delimiter = "";
        if (i < length) delimiter = ": ";
        if ($(this).find(":selected").attr('value')) {
            names[i] = $(this).find(":selected").text() + delimiter;
        } else if ($(this).is("input") && $(this).val()) {
            if ($(this).hasClass("from")) delimiter = "-";
            names[i] = $(this).val() + delimiter;
        }
        if (names[i]) nameString += names[i];
    });
    $("#summary").val(nameString);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested it fully, but something like this should work as well:

```
var $namers = $('.namer');

$namers.on('change', function () {
    var nameString = '';

    $namers.each(function(i) {
        var $this = $(this);
        var $selected = $this.find(':selected');

        if ($selected.attr('value')) {
            nameString += $selected.val() + ': ';
        } else if ($this.is('input') && $this.val()) {
            nameString += $this.val() + $this.hasClass('from') ? '-' : '';
        }
    });

    $('#summary').val(nameString);
});
```

The `i < length` condition will always be `false`, so you can remove that code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'll try that out. But I am wondering about your comment regarding i < length. As far as I can tell, it actually works as intended and evaluates to true except on the last item.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the rare cases where jquery gets in the way.  I recommend something like:

```
$("option").each( function() { this.value = $(this).text(); } );
$namers = $(".namer");
$names.on('change', function () {
    var length = $namers.length - 1;
    var nameString = "";
    $namers.each(function (i) {
        nameString += this.value;
        if (this.tagName == 'SELECT') nameString += ':';
        if (this.className == 'from') nameString += '-';
    });
    $("#summary").val(nameString);
});
```